# Can't run two functions after each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

When I execute this code, I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` and only `status` runs. What is the problem?

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    steam('status', 60000);
    steam('currently-playing', 60000);


});


function steam(mode, repeat) {

    // VARIABEL
    var checked = true;

    // HÄMTA
    steam = $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax-get/steam/' + mode.replace('-', '_'),
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#steam-' + mode).html('<div class="color-blue">Hämtar data från Steam API - var god vänta</div>');
        },

        success: function(s) {
            checked = false;
            $('#steam-' + mode).html(s);
        },

        error: function() {
            $('#steam-' + mode).html('<div class="color-red">Kunde inte hämta. Var god försök igen</div>');
        }
    });


    setInterval(function() {
        if(checked == false) {

            // HÄMTA
            steam = $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax-get/steam/' + mode.replace('_', '-'),
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(s) {
                    $('#steam-' + mode).html(s);
                },

                error: function() {
                    $('#steam-' + mode).html('<div class="color-red">Kunde inte hämta. Var god försök igen</div>');
                }
            });

        }
    }, repeat);

}
```

Comment: What's the error's line and column?

Comment: `steam = $.ajax({` is the culprit.

Comment: please add var before the variable `steam` in the `function steam` it sill resolve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement:

```
steam = $.ajax({
```

re-declares the global variable "steam" to be the return value from the `$.ajax()` call. It's overwriting the function definition, in other words.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is because you are overwriting that value of `steam` inside the function.

Say like bellow Or change the variable names.

```
var steam = $.ajax({
```

So it'll create a separate local variable to accept the return value from ajax. It won't overwrite the value of global `steam`.